# Why is Vim adding a newline? Is this a convention?

Tags: linux, vim, newlines

If I open Vim and type `itest<Esc>:wq` then I get a file that has no newlines *in Vim* but does seem to have a newline in the code:

```
$ vim -u NONE test.txt
$ cat test.txt | hd
00000000  74 65 73 74 0a                    |test.|
00000005
```

If I open Vim and type `itest<Return><Esc>:wq` then I get a file that has one newline *in Vim* but two newlines in the code:

```
$ rm test.txt
$ vim -u NONE test.txt
$ cat test.txt | hd
00000000  74 65 73 74 0a 0a                 |test..|
00000006
```

Note that I am opening Vim with `-u NONE` so there is no local configuration being used. Note also that this might be related to [a previous question of mine](https://superuser.com/questions/732534/is-vim-adding-the-windows-newlines).

This is my system info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux awsAlpha 3.2.0-60-virtual #91-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 19 04:13:28 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled May  4 2012 04:25:35)
Included patches: 1-429
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
```

I can confirm the exact same behaviour on this system as well:

```
$ uname -a
Linux bruno 3.5.0-48-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 10 23:18:29 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct 26 2012 16:45:33)
Included patches: 1-547
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
```

**Why is Vim adding a newline?** Is this a convention?

Here is some clarification about the `hd` command as installed on Ubuntu Server:

```
$ man hd | head -4
HEXDUMP(1)            BSD General Commands Manual            HEXDUMP(1)

NAME
     hexdump, hd — ASCII, decimal, hexadecimal, octal dump
```

Comment: It seems to be a convention. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14171297/3033711) how to disable it if you want. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-files-end-with-a-newline) the history of this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The convention for Unix text files is that every line is terminated by a newline, and that newlines are line terminators, not line separators.

When Vim saves a buffer as a file, it terminates every line with the end-of-line sequence for that file format, which for Unix is a newline. See

```
:help 'fileformat'
```

If you're using Unix text-processing tools, it's best to stick with this convention. However, if you have some need to not put a newline at the end of the last line of a file, you can do so. Vim considers such files to be "binary". See

```
:help 'binary'
:help edit-binary
```

Comment: oh that's interesting. So besides the famous \r\n vs \n.  Windows uses line separators and unix uses line terminators?  and is that documented anywhere?  I know it's defined here presumably applying to unix "ISO/IEC 9899:2011, Section §7.21.2 Streams says: A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into lines, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character"

Comment: but where is it documented that windows uses a line separator?

Answer (score 5):

Vim 8.0 now provides for this with the `fixeol` option. Specifically if you do:

```
:set nofixeol
```

then Vim *won't* add a trailing newline character at the end of the final line if the file didn't already have one.

That could go in a filetype plugin, or possibly even your `.vimrc`.

(This is an improvement on `:set binary` because it only affects the final line-break character, whereas `binary` also changes a bunch of other behaviours, which you probably don't want unless you're actually editing a binary file.)

A newly created file will still have a trailing line-break character by default. You can change that (and switch a file that already has a final newline to not having one) by additionally doing:

```
:set noeol
```

That has to be set specifically for each file you wish to change: loading a file into a buffer will always set `eol` to match the file's current state.

Answer (score 2):

Vim is not adding anything that you didn't put there yourself.

A "newline" character is *not* a "new line" and both examples are perfectly normal:

- in the first one, the file only contains one line so you get one "newline" character,
- in the second one, the file contains two lines so you get two "newline" characters.

Comment: It does add the newline. Test it as follows: `printf "\x41" > /tmp/test.txt`, then check that it has only single 'A' character with `xxd /tmp/test.txt`. Now `vim /tmp/test.txt<ENTER>:wq`. Check again to see the file having two bytes: 'A\n'.

Comment: Lines end with a newline character. You have one line thus you have one newline character.

Comment: Well, after `printf` here I had no well-formed "lines". After vim I have one. So, it does add something that I didn't put there.

Comment: What you `printf` is not a line unless you append `\n`. Being a text editor, Vim deals with lines by default, and *any* text you insert in the file *is* on, at the very least, a line, unless you explicitely tell Vim to not do that.

Answer (score 2):

Unterminated text files are evil for multiple reasons; here's one that I haven't seen mentioned yet:

In a hypothetical world where text files without a trailing newline are acceptable, there would be no difference between a file containing 0 lines and a file containing 1 blank line. They'd both be represented by a 0-byte file.

Inability to decide how many lines are in a file would be bad.

Comment: Text files in non-Unix systems contain zero or more complete lines, plus an incomplete line of zero or more characters.  An empty file does not contain a blank line; it contains zero complete lines and a partial line of zero characters.  Where's the ambiguity?

Comment: This "partial line" is an unpleasant concept. You can't have one anywhere other than the end of file, and you can't make a file that *doesn't* have a "partial line". It adds more breakage to file concatenation - even if you insert a newline between files you end up with something that isn't semantically equivalent to the original pair of files (because with 2 files you had 2 partial lines, and one of them became something different.) An inelegant proposal.

Comment: The fact that concatenating files will cause any partial line at the end of the first to prepended to the next file is generally icky in cases where both files contain full lines (it can sometimes be useful to concatenate files which don't contain any full lines), but it is what it is.  Unix does not forbid the construction of text files ending with partial lines, and I believe concatenating such files will behave as in MSDOS.  The difference I think is that many DOS based editors have historically taken the view that loading and immediately saving a file should yield a new file...

Comment: ...which is bit-identical to the old one (registered users of early versions of PC-Write were instructed to use it to open a copy of the executable, switch to overwrite mode, find a certain string, and replace it with their serial number!).  Forcing files to end with newlines when saving them would violate that constraint.

Comment: This sounds exactly like the world I live in, where my box containing 0 oranges is indistinguishable from my box containing 0 apples.

Answer (score 1):

Using the 'j' command you can join all the lines into one.

If you also want to remove the LF or CRLF on the last line do the following
in vi.

```
$ vi file
:set binary
:set noeol
:w!
:f          look for [noeol] on the status line
:q
```